# Is there any command to export graph from GraphDB?

Tags: command, export, sparql, graphdb

I am aware of the export functionality provided by the GraphDB workbench. However, I would like to find out if there is any command line utility to export the graph using the console quickly.

For example, there is `importrdf` command to load the data offline. There should be a command to export data as well. https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/command-line-tools.html

Thanks.

Comment: If GraphDB is running you can use the rdf4j api + curl - take a look at the API, specifically, the [statements](https://rdf4j.org/documentation/reference/rest-api/#repository-statements) endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `export` using  `bin/storage-tool` script.

Uses the source index (`srcIndex`) to export repository data to the destination file (`destFile`). Supported destination file extension formats: .trig, .ttl, .nq. For example to dump the repository data using the POS index into a f.trig file:

`bin/storage-tool -command=export -storage=/repo/storage -srcIndex=pos -destFile=/repo/storage/f.trig`

More details here:
https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/storage-tool.html#examples